# Select string between two groups with bash regex

Tags: regex, bash

I have a string like this:

```
zone "example.com" {
    type slave;
    file "db.example.com";
    masters { x.x.x.x; };
};

zone "foo.com" {
    type slave;
    file "db.foo.com";
    masters { x.x.x.x; };
};

...
```

I would like to delete a specific zone.

I know how to delete it once I have the regex:

```
sudo sed -i '$REGEX' /file/path
```

But I am not quite sure of the regex itself. I know the beginning would be `(zone "example.com" {)` and the end would be something like `(};\s};)` but how do i also include the content in between?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sed -i '/example\.com/,/^$/d' filename
```

This will delete lines in the range starting with the first the line containing "example.com" and ending with a blank line.

Comment: I've well overcomplicated this haha

Comment: is there any need for the '\' before the `.com` I tried without and still working.

Comment: The period matches any character, so the target `/example.com/` without the \ will also match `example7com` or `example com`.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this in sed

```
REGEX=example
sed -n "/$REGEX/{h};/^$/h;x;/$REGEX/{x;d};/$REGEX/"'!{x;p}' file

zone "foo.com" {
    type slave;
    file "db.foo.com";
    masters { x.x.x.x; };
};
```

Comment: This is duplicating everything else in the file

Comment: @Maximilian shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk you can handle this using a null record separator i.e. `-v RS=`:

```
awk -v name='example.com' -v RS= '!($0 ~ name)' zones
zone "foo.com" {
    type slave;
    file "db.foo.com";
    masters { x.x.x.x; };
};
```